# The reason that python runs out of memory when loops are used to search through lists

Tags: python, list, loops, search, memory

This is the question I needed to write a program for:

Write a program to open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split function.
For each word, check to see if the word is already in a list. If the word is not in the list, add it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical
order.

The text file includes the following lines:

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

I am trying to understand why Python returns "MemoryError" when I use this code:

```
fhand=open("romeo.txt")
binlist=["a"]
for myline in fhand:
    myline=myline.rstrip()
    mylist=myline.split()
    for word in mylist:
        for binword in binlist:
            if word==binword:
                continue
            else:
                binlist.append(word)
binlist.sort()
print(binlist)
```

However, this code works well:

```
fhand=open("romeo.txt")
binlist=[]
for myline in fhand:
    myline=myline.rstrip()
    mylist=myline.split()
    for word in mylist:
        if word in binlist:
            continue
        else:
            binlist.append(word)
binlist.sort()
print(binlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the logic of your inner for-loop. You are saying:

```
For each word in binlist:
    If word is EQUAL to binword, then proceed to the next word
    If word is NOT equal to binword, then add it to the end of binlist
```

This means that your code could add the word to the end of binlist, **and then keep going through the list.** This could result in an infinite loop, as you'll just keep iterating through a list that's constantly expanding.

Answer (score 0):

With the first code you're adding words to the list multiple times, even when the word is already in binlist. You're also modifying (appending) the list while looping through the same list, this results in an ever expanding list and a loop that never terminates.

You probably want to do this with a set instead

```
fhand=open("romeo.txt")
binlist={}
for myline in fhand:
    set.update(myline.split())
binlist = sorted(binlist)
print(binlist)
```